# IR LED power density calculation

Tags: led, infrared

I made the basic IR LED circuit shown to augment the existing system on a night vision security camera. 
No datasheet was found for the LEDs so I just measured the current to extract the power of ~0.1W total for the 4 LEDs. The beam angle is 30deg.

Is the calculation below correct to determine the approximate power at a distance of 0.2m from the radiating source?

Specifically want to make sure that power density is within the 'safe' region guideline I was able to find online (~100 W/m<sup>2</sup> at a distance of ~0.2 m for up to 1000 sec). 
The light emitted seems to be a comparable brightness to the in-built IR camera illuminator when viewed through the IR camera. 
Commercial IR arrays for security cameras I was able to find online seem to be in the ~4 W up to 20 W+ so I assume this 0.1 W is in the fairly safe region.

Here is the LED I used: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00BPAS0BA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BPAS0BA)

[image]

Comment: Good question. Bad circuit. Someone who can do the physics calculations will hopefully also explain why.

Comment: @Pipe: The circuit is poor (the power is wasted in the bias resistor). Really just wanted to measure the current/power to determine the power density at some fixed distance and determine safe or not with a basic calculation. The calculation seems reasonable to me, but I don't know much about LED physics. Hopefully some expert can provide feedback.

Comment: A circuit like this won't work well in real life. One does not simply put diodes in parallel (where there is a straight connection between the anodes and cathodes). You need a 100ohm resistor for each of the diodes.

Comment: You are assuming that your total power of the LEDs is actually converted to light which it isn't. So your calculations should be a worst case view and the power density will probably be even lower than what you calculated. And typically you will also have some illumination outside of the angle (most of the time it's given for 50% to 50% of the peak), reducing your real power density even further.

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful comments. I agree that the assumption of all power consumed is radiated (100% efficiency) is on the conservative side, but I want to quote a max worst-case value@Arsenel: but does the power density calculation (assuming full 0.1W) spread out over a circle of radius defined by the distance and angle seem correct?